# What are Geometry Nodes Attributes?

Tags: experimental-features, geometry-nodes

Precisely what are attributes in the context of geometry nodes?
I have been able to find little to no documentation and/or community info on this subject.
Explaining or linking to an in-depth explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: I did a tutorial on that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YudUfp0N2QU

Comment: There isn't much documentation on it because they aren't done developing them yet

Comment: I am aware that there is no documentation on the geometry nodes' aspect of it, but attributes, in general, appear to have existed for a long time in shaders [see attribute node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/attribute.html). I assume that the terminology is the same, and most likely the underlying backend as well.

Answer (score 2):

the attributes are to control particles you can use them to change particles scale, rotation, etc...

I have a tutorial you can watch here: https://youtu.be/YudUfp0N2QU

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, what exactly is happening in the gif? The nodes are unreadable.. It would be very useful if you would [edit] and add an explanation.

Comment: I added the node setup and a link to a tutorial that shows a bit how the geometry nodes work.

Answer (score 2):

Every point referenced in an object has an attribute, whether that is vertexes or points generated using a point distribute node. An attribute stores a bit of information of every one of these points. This could be a points scale, location or rotation. It could also be a user generated value such as a vertex group. Think of them as variables for every point in an object.