# How attributes fit into the new fields-based geometry nodes workflow

Tags: geometry-nodes

How exactly do you work with attributes in geometry nodes after the implementation of the fields-based system?  I saw that this question (or the equivalent of it at the time) was asked and answered in January '21 ([Geometry Nodes Attributes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/207686/geometry-nodes-attributes)), but that was before the introduction of the fields-based system, which basically makes any prior documentation about working with attributes obsolete.

There are currently 3 nodes that work with attributes, and I have no idea what they do or how to use them.

How exactly do attributes currently fit into the big picture of the geometry nodes workflow?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blender 3.0.0 - How to use a vertex group in geometry nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/241925/blender-3-0-0-how-to-use-a-vertex-group-in-geometry-nodes)

Comment: @BlenderUser123 somewhat, but it also brings in new questions, like how to I access attributes like crease?  There is no input node for this.  Also, I still don't understand what the 3 attribute-related nodes do.